# setPin() shows error in eclipse that "setPin() is undefined for BluetoothDevice"

Tags: android, bluetooth

I don't find many *BluetoothDevice* methodes such as , `setPasskey()`, `setPin()`, `setPairingConfirmation()`, `setRemoteOutOfBandData()`.

I searched on *Android* site as well but I don't find it. When I use these methods in my program in eclipse it shows me an error: its undefined for the type *BluetoothDevice*.

Are these obsolete now? If yes then what are the new methods of same type.

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that paring process is performed only by applications delivered with a platform!
This means that this application have access to hidden API. For example you can find [hidden API for Bluetooth here](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html).
It is strongly recommended to not use hidden API since it can change without warning in next Android release.
If you are still planning to use this API safest way is to use reflection:

```
try {
    Class<? extends BluetoothDevice> c = device.getClass(); // BluetoothDevice.class
    Method createBond = c.getMethod("createBond");
    Object result = createBond.invoke(device);
    Boolean castedResult = (Boolean)result;
    Log.d(TAG, "Result: " + castedResult.toString());
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There is also alternative way to [easy use hidden API](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/), but I didn't try it.